# Why is that = this in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have snippet of js code like this

```
Customer.prototype.parseAddress = function(data){
   this.address = data.address;
}
Customer.prototype.loadAddress = function(){
   ...
}
```

I need to implement the loadAddress function.

Can someone explain me why this snippet of code is correct

```
var that = this;
$.get('data.xml', function(data){
    that.parseAddress(data);
});
```

and following is not correct

```
$.get('data.xml', function(data){
    this.parseAddress(data);
});
```

Comment: It is hard to tell because there isn't a big enough picture. 'this' refers to the encapsulating object. Depending on where you call it (or assign it to a variable) it will refer to whichever object it is called within.

Comment: `this` inside success `$.get()` callback is referring to jqXHR object

Comment: depending on where this is in the code it changes. It is the execution context. Inside the function, the execution context is different than before

Comment: This is too complicated for SO you need to read up on scope in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, `this` is a special contextual keyword that changes depending on where you use it.

By doing `that = this;` you're saving what `this` means, so you don't need to worry about whether or not `this` means what you thought it did.

```
my_func = function() {
  var that = this;
  console.log(this); //prints one thing

  my_inner_func = function()
    {
      console.log(this); //prints another
      console.log(that); //prints what the first log printed
    }
  my_inner_func();
}
```

Comment: Can you very briefly explain what `this` is itself?

Comment: Checkout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this. It's basically `self.` in Python, but changes what `self` points to depending on how deeply its nested.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that when you call a function you need to pass the context of the function, otherwise, the context will be the new one specified by the query. You should check the following concepts (call, apply and bind).

You can write:

```
 $.get('data.xml', function(data){
   this.parseAddress(data);
}.bind(this));
```

A good link reference to study about it is:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: I am sorry. You can't use call or apply, I just wanted to help him with similar concepts.

Comment: thank you, this info was helpful.

Comment: @PedroAugusto Don't worry, this answering the question in some way ;)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is because `this` is contextual and can change within the callback.

What I mean by the statement is

```
this.parseAddress
```

`parseAddress` has been defined on `this`. However when the callback function is called, `this` may not be the object you expect, jQuery does this quite a bit. You therefore can't access other properties of the original `this` from within the callback.

The simplest way to handle it is to keep a reference to the original `this` by storing it in `that`. Now you can always refer back to the original object and access more properties due to original reference in `that` being accessible within the scope of the jQuery callback.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? I'm not sure what is wrong with the answer?